# Как отправить POST запрос с Android-приложения, используя Jsoup?

Tags: android

У меня есть Android-приложение, в котором имеется всего одна строка для ввода и кнопка для отправки.

Мне необходимо вводимые данные передать в html-форму на локальный сервер (127.0.0.1:5000/page1) не открывая страницу на мобильном приложении.

Как это реализовать?

Начал читать о Jsoup, но **подробных** примеров как в моём случае, я не нашёл (всё реализовывается через php).

Comment: Jsoup - для парсинга HTML, а не для сетевых запросов. Для последних возьмите OkHttp (возможно, в связке с Retrofit, что сложнее, но оправдано при большом кол-ве разных запросов)